# In agar.io, how much overlap is needed to eat another player or virus?

Tags: agar.io

Let

- `R` = the radius of the larger circle
- `r` = the radius of the smaller circle
- `d` = the distance between the centers

When two circles touch (`d < R + r`), nothing happens. However, I noticed that even when the center of a smaller circle is in a larger circle (`d < R`), nothing happens until they move slightly closer.

What is the condition for eating other objects? How much overlap is needed?

Comment: This is a very interesting question. I think if nobody answers it for another while, I might offer a bounty. Maybe it's possible to look at the source code of the page? But I bet it's decided server side, so tests would have to be made.

Comment: @Fabian, it's for a clone rather than the original. Unless someone does some testing or leaks the code, we might never know the real answer. I accepted the answer because it's the best answer so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a clone of the game available on [Github](https://github.com/huytd/agar.io-clone), however it may be modified from the original game.  It's stated in the description that the real game is closed source, and that this clone is for people who would like to play their own version of the game with whatever modifications they wish to make.  That being said, I have no reason to think that someone would have altered this portion of the code below to change how collisions work.

There is a function called [`collisionCheck`](https://github.com/huytd/agar.io-clone/blob/master/src/server/server.js#L531), which I believe to be the section of code that controls if you will be consumed or not by another user.  Looking at it, it performs some math using the two users X and Y coordinates, and then also checks if the User's radius is larger than the others.

```
function collisionCheck(collision) {
    if (collision.aUser.mass > collision.bUser.mass * 1.1  && collision.aUser.radius > Math.sqrt(Math.pow(collision.aUser.x - collision.bUser.x, 2) + Math.pow(collision.aUser.y - collision.bUser.y, 2))*1.75) {
        console.log('[DEBUG] Killing user: ' + collision.bUser.id);
        console.log('[DEBUG] Collision info:');
        console.log(collision);

        var numUser = util.findIndex(users, collision.bUser.id);
        if (numUser > -1) {
            if(users[numUser].cells.length > 1) {
                users[numUser].massTotal -= collision.bUser.mass;
                users[numUser].cells.splice(collision.bUser.num, 1);
            } else {
                users.splice(numUser, 1);
                io.emit('playerDied', { name: collision.bUser.name });
                sockets[collision.bUser.id].emit('RIP');
            }
        }
        currentPlayer.massTotal += collision.bUser.mass;
        collision.aUser.mass += collision.bUser.mass;
    }
}
```

What we want to examine more is the `if` statement at the top:

```
if (collision.aUser.mass > collision.bUser.mass * 1.1  && collision.aUser.radius > Math.sqrt(Math.pow(collision.aUser.x - collision.bUser.x, 2) + Math.pow(collision.aUser.y - collision.bUser.y, 2))*1.75)
```

What this is saying is:

- If User A's mass is greater than User B's mass times 1.1 (110% of User B's mass)

**AND**

- User A's Radius is greater than the square root of User A's X coordinate minus User B's X coordinate to the power of 2 plus User A's Y coordinate minus User B's Y coordinate to the power of 2 multiplied by 1.75.

I think what you are primarily interested in is the second portion of the `if` (the part after the `&&`), since you want to know how much overlap is needed.  For this, lets make an example.

- User A's X Coordinate: 50
- User A's Y Coordinate: 100
- User A's Radius: 50
- User A's Mass: 100
- User B's X Coordinate: 75
- User B's Y Coordinate: 120
- User B's Mass: 90

Lets plug these values into the part of the `if` statement that follows the `&&`:

```
Math.sqrt(Math.Pow(50 - 75, 2) + Math.Pow(100 - 120, 2)) * 1.75 = ~42.35
```

Now lets look at the rest of the `if` statement, with our answer of ~42.35 put in place, as well as the other variables above:

```
if (100 > 99 && 50 > 42.35) { //User A's Mass > User B's Mass * 1.1 and User A's Radius > The evaluation made above

 //do the stuff in here

}
```

So, when the expression inside of the `if` evaluates to true, it will drop down into the statements code block, and run any code in there.  For this statement, it looks like it outputs some text to the console, takes User B out of the game, does some other `if` statement logic (I'm not quite sure what), and adds User B's mass to User A's mass. So to answer how much overlap is needed, I suppose the correct answer would be if **User A's Radius is greater than the square root of User A's X coordinate minus User B's X coordinate to the power of 2 plus User A's Y coordinate minus User B's Y coordinate to the power of 2 multiplied by 1.75.**  Don't forget however, that User A's mass must also be greater than 110% of User B's mass.

For viruses, I believe your mass only has to be larger than the Viruses mass for it to split you.  [The Wiki](http://agario.wikia.com/wiki/Virus) for viruses states this, and that is what is appears to be from actually playing the game.  I *think* [the code](https://github.com/huytd/agar.io-clone/blob/master/src/server/server.js#L571) for this is:

```
if(virusCollision > 0 && currentCell.mass > virus[virusCollision].mass) {
          sockets[currentPlayer.id].emit('virusSplit', z);
          virus.splice(virusCollision, 1);
        }
```

Edit:

**How Mass is calculated:**

I found this bit of code in a different javascript file called util.js.  It is referenced a lot in the server.js file, which is where the code above is from. Based off the comment in the code, this looks like how mass is determined:

```
// determine mass from radius of circle
exports.massToRadius = function (mass) {
    return 4 + Math.sqrt(mass) * 6;
};
```

It seems to be the square root of the mass of the player times 6 plus 4.  All players start with a `defaultPlayerMass` of 10, which can viewed in the [config.json](https://github.com/huytd/agar.io-clone/blob/master/config.json#L8) file.

Comment: This is a great analysis of how big you have to be, but not how much overlap it needs.

Comment: Btw, all that square and root stuff means that your radius has to be 1.75 times as long as the diagonal of an imaginary square around the other person's circle. Why exactly I don't know, they could have just picked a different factor (for example a nice round 5), because players are always circles (except if squished, but I don't think that matters much and it probably shouldn't change who you can eat).

Comment: Wait, this means that your radius has to be five times as much as the other person's radius? That sounds too much for me.

Comment: Wait, no, I read it wrong. It means that your diameter has to be at least 87.5% of the distance between you and the other player. But wouldn't that mean that you could eat players without touching them? Or are distances measured from the centers?

Comment: How is the mass calculated? In your example it's the radius*2, but the most reasonable formula would be Pi*r².

Comment: @Fabian I added the mass calculation.  I would think the distances are also measured from the center of the players for the reason you said.

Comment: So `m=((r-4)/6)²`. I'll calculate some more things.

Comment: Ok, so it's all ok. Since if the diameter is 87.5% of the distance, the circles still touch, it's no problem. I confused radius and diameter a bit.

Comment: Are there videos/images showing that this behaves the same as the original? Or can the developers tell you what they did to create it?

Comment: Hang on, I'll prettyprint these equations in LaTeX.

Comment: I don't know what that means, but does it confirm that the behaviour is the same in the original game?

Comment: SE just reminded me that my bounty expires soon. So, is there supporting evidence that this behaviour is the same in the original game? Eating another player on the official website could be recorded, replayed in this clone and looked at if the eating happens at the same moment. That a few times with different parameters and I would consider it confirmed.

Comment: @Fabian I do not know how to go about doing that, nor do I think I could do it in a reasonable amount of time.  I also doubt there is anything I can find from researching further as well.  I think my answer is as good as it will get for now.

Comment: So this incorrect answer is OK but mine is deleted? Oh well

Answer (score 2):

Here's a summary of [Timmy Jim's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/325300/29482) for [an agar.io clone](https://github.com/huytd/agar.io-clone/blob/master/src/server/server.js).

- `(R-4)² > 1.1(r-4)²` and `1.75d < R` to eat players
- `d < R` to eat viruses

Interestingly, `d < R - r` when the small circle is entirely inside the large circle. `1.75d < R` means when `R > 7r/3` (the larger circle is 2.3x larger in radius, or ~5.4x larger in mass), the small circle can survive even if it's entirely inside the large one.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm... I think I've heard this before. Of what I remember, I think you have to be about 110-115% the size of the person you are trying to eat.

Comment: Oh wait i just re-read the question... Well now you know how much bigger you need to be to eat them.

Comment: It's half of the condition (relating r and R), so it answers half of the question.

Answer (score -3):

about 1 half of you, remember only if they are bigger than you they can catch you!

Answer (score -3):

When your diameter is twice as big as the object you want to eat.

Comment: That only involves R and r, not d. But d is the number in question.

Comment: Half of the condition depends on r and R, so it answers half of the question.